# How to spread projects across active years?

Tags: sql, r, excel, excel-2013

I have an Excel spread sheet with over 10000 projects and each project has a start date and end date different from the other. I need to spread the projects across the years they are active in order to have an exact count by year. How do I do it starting from this example?

```
start date   end date     entityNo  amount
4/1/2001     8/31/2012      1         500
1/1/2005     12/31/2007     2         100
```

The solution I thought of initially was to get the difference between the start date and the end date (end date - start date + 1) in Excel so that I have the duration in days for each project. After getting the number of days, e.g., 4100 days, I divide the duration by the total number of days in a year(365.25 days) which will give me the range of years but then I got stuck when it came to assigning each project to the correct years.

Expected output for a dataset of over 10,000 projects:

```
start date   end date         no of years  entityNo  amount
4/1/2001     8/31/2012                11            1         500
2002
2003
2004
2005
2006
2007 upto 8/31/2012
```

followed by another project with a different entity number

```
start date       end date      entity no      amount
   1/1/2005     12/31/2007     2              100
```

output

```
years       entity no     amount
1/1/2005    2             100
2006        2             100
2/31/2007   2             100
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are you trying to do it with, Sql, R, Excel? Why the three tags. What have you tried so far? Your example isn't really clear. What do you mean by "spread the projects..."?

Comment: I would like a response based on either r, excel or sql. I mean that distribute the projects in all the active years if one was running 11 years from the year 2001-2012 it should appear 11 times if another was running 5 years it should appear 5 times.

Comment: How do you mean "Appear"? Can you please show an expected output sample? Do you simply want to copy the data into X many rows?

Comment: @BruceWayne yes that is what i would like to do

Comment: Wait - did you just edit the post to ask for a different type of output? I had a simple macro that would copy the data down X times, where X is the number of years. Now it looks like you want to add a column of the number of years? Is that all?  Where do you want the year to go? ("I would like to see it in 2002, 2003...")?

Comment: @BruceWayne hope i more clearer now

Comment: @daisym If you keep changing your expected output, there is nothing I can do.

Comment: @ycw I am sorry about the edit but the last edit was the output i wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This solution needs the r package `lubridate`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Create example data frame
dat <- tribble(
  ~`start date`, ~`end date`, ~`entityNo`, ~`amount`,
  "4/1/2001",  "8/31/2012",   1,         500,
  "1/1/2005",  "12/31/2007",  2,         100
)

dat %>%
  mutate(`start date` = mdy(`start date`), `end date` = mdy(`end date`)) %>%
  mutate(`start year` = year(`start date`), `end year` = year(`end date`)) %>%
  mutate(`no of years` = `end year` - `start year`) %>%
  select(`start date`, `end date`, `no of years`, entityNo, amount)
```

or you can use some string manipulation method.

```
dat %>%
  mutate(`no of years` = as.numeric(substring(`end date`, nchar(`end date`) - 3)) -
           as.numeric(substring(`start date`, nchar(`start date`) - 3))) %>%
  select(`start date`, `end date`, `no of years`, entityNo, amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest edit, the OP wants to have a breakdown of the duration of each project by calendar year. This can be accomplished by utilizing the `foverlaps()` function of the `data.table` package.

## Read data

```
library(data.table)
projects <- fread(
"start_date   end_date     entityNo  amount
4/1/2001     8/31/2012      1         500
1/1/2005     12/31/2007     2         100")
```

`fread()` can be used to read `csv` files fast from disk. Here, a convenience feature is used which allows to read data from a character variable.

## Prepare data

```
library(lubridate)
# convert dates from character to Date class
date_cols <- c("start_date", "end_date")
projects[, (date_cols) := lapply(.SD, mdy), .SDcols = date_cols]

# compute duration of project = number of years in which project was active
projects[, years_active := year(end_date) - year(start_date) + 1]
```

Note that `years_active` is different to `no of years` as given by the OP. `years_active` is the number of rows needed to spread the data.

## Create date range for computing overlaps

```
date_range <- projects[, .(year = seq(year(min(start_date)), 
                                      year(max(end_date))))]
date_range[, start_in_year := ymd(paste0(year, "-01-01"))]
date_range[, end_in_year := ymd(paste0(year, "-12-31"))]
setkey(date_range, start_in_year, end_in_year)

date_range
#    year start_in_year end_in_year
# 1: 2001    2001-01-01  2001-12-31
# 2: 2002    2002-01-01  2002-12-31
# 3: 2003    2003-01-01  2003-12-31
# ...
#10: 2010    2010-01-01  2010-12-31
#11: 2011    2011-01-01  2011-12-31
#12: 2012    2012-01-01  2012-12-31
```

Note that this approach can be extended to create a break down of durations by quarters, months, ISO weeks, or days.

## Compute overlapping intervals

```
projects_by_year <- foverlaps(projects, date_range, by.x = date_cols)
# adjust start_in_year to coincide with project start date
projects_by_year[, start_in_year := pmax(start_in_year, start_date)]
# adjust end_in_year to coincide with project end date
projects_by_year[, end_in_year := pmin(end_in_year, end_date)]

projects_by_year
#    year start_in_year end_in_year start_date   end_date entityNo amount years_active
# 1: 2001    2001-04-01  2001-12-31 2001-04-01 2012-08-31        1    500           12
# 2: 2002    2002-01-01  2002-12-31 2001-04-01 2012-08-31        1    500           12
# 3: 2003    2003-01-01  2003-12-31 2001-04-01 2012-08-31        1    500           12
# ...
#10: 2010    2010-01-01  2010-12-31 2001-04-01 2012-08-31        1    500           12
#11: 2011    2011-01-01  2011-12-31 2001-04-01 2012-08-31        1    500           12
#12: 2012    2012-01-01  2012-08-31 2001-04-01 2012-08-31        1    500           12
#13: 2005    2005-01-01  2005-12-31 2005-01-01 2007-12-31        2    100            3
#14: 2006    2006-01-01  2006-12-31 2005-01-01 2007-12-31        2    100            3
#15: 2007    2007-01-01  2007-12-31 2005-01-01 2007-12-31        2    100            3
```

Project 1 is spread over 12 years/rows, projetct 2 over 3 years. `start_in_year` and `end_in_year` are adjusted to match the correct start and end *dates* in the respctive start and end *years* of each project.

This is hopefully the expected result.

---

## Compute aggregates by year

The long format is well suited to compute aggregates per year. For instance, thenumber of projects per year:

```
projects_by_year[, .N, by = year]
#    year N
# 1: 2001 1
# 2: 2002 1
# 3: 2003 1
# 4: 2004 1
# 5: 2005 2
# 6: 2006 2
# 7: 2007 2
# 8: 2008 1
# 9: 2009 1
#10: 2010 1
#11: 2011 1
#12: 2012 1
```

Or the total amounts per year:

```
projects_by_year[, sum(amount), by = year]
#    year  V1
# 1: 2001 500
# 2: 2002 500
# 3: 2003 500
# 4: 2004 500
# 5: 2005 600
# 6: 2006 600
# 7: 2007 600
# 8: 2008 500
# 9: 2009 500
#10: 2010 500
#11: 2011 500
#12: 2012 500
```

Comment: Did one of the answers solve your problem? If so, please, accept and/or upvote it so that the question is marked as answered. Otherwise, please, let us know why the answer didn't work for you so that it can be improved for the benefit of you and other SO users. Thank you.